# Add new button after text changed

Tags: html, angularjs

I`m using Angualr for my web.
I have this part in html code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
              <div class="text-form" style="float: left;">Companion URL</div>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Companion URL" class="companion-url-box" ng-model="newCreative.companionUrl">
            </div>
```

I want to add method (in the Controller) that when the text change, it will add a new button down.
How can I do it? I can`t understand how ng-change works.

thanks

Comment: when the text change based on what condition will the button gonna added ??

Comment: sorry, can`t understand the question

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-change gives and example of the ng-chage and you might want to check the AngularJS site out as well. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `ng-if` to check if `newCreative.companionUrl` exists in scope :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="text-form" style="float: left;">Companion URL</div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Companion URL" class="companion-url-box" ng-model="newCreative.companionUrl">
  <input type="button" value="Click me" ng-if="newCreative.companionUrl">
</div>
```

You can also use a function to validate button visibility :

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="SampleController as ctrl">

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="text-form" style="float: left;">Companion URL</div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Companion URL" class="companion-url-box" ng-model="newCreative.companionUrl">
      <input type="button" value="Click me" ng-if="ctrl.isButtonAvailable()">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('SampleController', function ($scope) {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.isButtonAvailable = function() {
        if(!$scope.newCreative) {
            return false;
        }
        // Ensure companion url starts with https:// using a regular expression
        return /^https:\/\//.test($scope.newCreative.companionUrl);
    }
});
```

**Working example**

Check out this Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/n8VtJrenePGf9hCbmzWJ

Answer (score 0):

You can use the directives ng-change on input and ng-if or ng-show on button, plus a little code on controller.

Check this:

http://codepen.io/mQuixaba/pen/oZqXWG?editors=1111

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <label for="input">Text:</label>
  <input type="text" id="input" ng-model="text" ng-change="showButton=true"/>
  <button ng-if="showButton" ng-click="hideButton()">My Button</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyController', function($scope){
      $scope.showButton = false;
      $scope.text = "My text";

      $scope.hideButton = function() {
        $scope.showButton = false;
      }
    });
```